# How much memory is used for a particular process

Tags: memory, portable-batch-system

I am using qsub for submitting jobs on the cluster(SGE). What i want to know is when i submit a qsub job and after it finishes, I want to find how much memory it actually uses up so next time I provide it with required memory just in case.

I used this command after my job was finished to check the memory requirements of my submitted job

```
qacct -j job-ID
```

But I got this output

/opt/gridengine/default/common/accounting: No such file or directory no jobs running since startup

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance